# Richface: a4j:mediaOutput, data is 'null'

Tags: java, file-upload, richfaces, output

I'm getting nullpointer when i try to display an image i upload.

I follow the example from: [Richfaces Showcase](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=fileUpload)

Error: **javax.el.ELException: ...[path]... createContent="#{imageBean.paint}": java.lang.NullPointerException**

Used source code:

**ImageBean.java**

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class ImageBean implements Serializable{
  private ImageData imageData= new ImageData();

  public void listener(FileUploadEvent event) throws Exception {
    UploadedFile item = event.getUploadedFile();
    imageData = new ImageData();
    imageData.setName(item.getName());
    imageData.setData(item.getData());
  }

  public void paint(OutputStream stream, Object object) throws IOException {
    stream.write(getFile().getData());
    stream.close();
  }

  // getters and setters for file
```

**uploadImage.xhtml**

```
<h:form>
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="top,top">
            <rich:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{imageBean.listener}" id="upload" acceptedTypes="jpg, gif, png, bmp"
                ontyperejected="alert('Only JPG, GIF, PNG and BMP files are accepted');" maxFilesQuantity="1">
                <a4j:ajax event="uploadcomplete" execute="@none" render="info" />
            </rich:fileUpload>
            <h:panelGroup id="info" layout="block">
                <rich:panel bodyClass="info">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Uploaded Files Info" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="Geen foto beschikbaar" rendered="#{imageBean.size==0}" />
                    <a4j:mediaOutput element="img" mimeType="image/jpeg" createContent="#{imageBean.paint}"
                        value="#{imageBean.file.name}" style="width:100px; height:100px;" cacheable="false">
                    </a4j:mediaOutput>
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                        <h:outputText value="File Name:" />
                        <h:outputText value="#{imageBean.file.name}" />
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </rich:panel>
                <br />
            </h:panelGroup>
        </h:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
```

According to my debugger:
imageDate gets data in the upload **listener()**
but is null in the **paint()**

My thought would be then that i should put my scope bigger.
So I have set it to **@SessionScoped**

**Web.xml**:

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>createTempFiles</param-name>
  <param-value>false</param-value>
 </context-param>
```

I have tried both true and false

Using Richfaces: 4.3.2

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to render the image when no file was uploaded. The `<a4j:mediaOutput>` needs to be rendered conditionally.

Comment: I don't think i understand you correctly. as far i know i trigger the render on <a4j:ajax event="uploadcomplete" execute="@none" render="info" /> inside the upload

Comment: You do, but the first render happens when the page loads and at that time there is no image to paint.

Comment: true, Probably i should have mentioned it but i get this nullpointer when the screen gets loaded and also when i upload a file.
The first nullpointer i want to 'fix' by painting the default image, i just havent made that code yet because i cant get the upload part to work.